# Android - Adding items from a table in SQLite to a collection list

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

I am still new to android and i am still learning how to use SQLite.

This a function I am making to get data from a database randomly and store it in a list. The problem here is that when it first runs on the device, the only thing I can get is the last row in the database. I am not sure I understand what is happening here.

```
public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
        List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
        // Select All Query

        String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + ";" ;
        dba = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dba.rawQuery(query, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Question quest = new Question();
                quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
                quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(2));
                quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(3));
                quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(4));
                quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(5));
                quest.setISIMAGE(cursor.getInt(6));

                quesList.add(quest);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return quest list
        cursor.close();
        dba.close();
        return quesList;
    }
```

This is the activity that uses the function

```
public class Testactivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<Question> quesList;
    int score;
    int qid = 0;
    //static int n;

    Question currentQ;
    QuizHelper db;
    TextView scored, tv_score;
    TextView txtQuestion, txtCounter;
    Button button1, button2, button3;
    public static String ans;
    ImageView img;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.testactivity2);

        QuizHelper db = new QuizHelper(this);
        quesList = db.getAllQuestions();
        currentQ = quesList.get(qid);

        this.score = 0;
        tv_score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        tv_score.setText(String.valueOf(score));
        txtCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_counter);

        db = new QuizHelper(this);
        quesList = db.getAllQuestions();

        currentQ = quesList.get(qid);


        txtQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtQuestion);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgQuestion);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        scored = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I'm here!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        //db.getQuestion();
        setQuestionView();
        // button click listeners
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // passing the button text to other method
                // to check whether the answer is correct or not
                // same for all three buttons
                getAnswer(button1.getText().toString());
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getAnswer(button2.getText().toString());
            }
        });

        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getAnswer(button3.getText().toString());
            }
        });

    }

    private void setQuestionView(){
        //display control
        txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
        button1.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
        button2.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
        button3.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());

        qid++;
    }

    public void getAnswer(String AnswerString) {
        if (currentQ.getANSWER().equals(AnswerString)) {

            // if conditions matches increase the int (score) by 1
            // and set the text of the score view
            score++;
            scored.setText(" " + this.score);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CORRECT!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            db.getAllQuestions();
            setQuestionView();
            //db.getQuestion();
        } else {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Testactivity.this, result.class);


            // if unlucky start activity and finish the game

           // Intent intent = new Intent(Testactivity.this, result.class);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WRONG, SORRY!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //db.getQuestion();
          //  db.getScore(test_entry.username, this.score);

            // passing the int value
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("score", score); // Your score
            intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        if(qid < 3 ) {
            currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
            setQuestionView();
        }else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(Testactivity.this,result.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("score", score);
            intent.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Is there something missing / wrong with my getAllQuestions() function or am i calling it wrong?

This is how my database was implemented as well as how the data was inserted

QuizHelper(Database Helper):

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        //ta = new Testactivity();
        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_OPTA + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTB+ " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTC+ " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_ISIMAGE + " INTEGER(11));";

        String USER_RECORD = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + " (" + USER_NAME + " TEXT, " + USER_SCORE + " INTEGER);";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(USER_RECORD);

        addQuestion(db);
    }
```

Data

```
private void addQuestion(SQLiteDatabase db) {


        Question q1 = new Question("A driver who got caught on drugs or alchohol is punishable by", "Suspension of license","Six months of imprisonment","All of the above","All of the above", 0);
        this.addQuestiontoDB(q1,db);

        Question q2 = new Question("What is the fine for driving without a valid license?", "Php 500.00","Php 500.00 and vehicle impounded","Php 3, 000.00","Php 3, 000.00", 0);
        this.addQuestiontoDB(q2,db);

        Question q3 = new Question("If you are caught, how many days does it take to fix your case and redeem the license", "30 days","15 days","10 days","15 days", 0);
        this.addQuestiontoDB(q3,db);

    }

    // Adding new question
    public void addQuestiontoDB(Question question, SQLiteDatabase db) {

        //db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        //values.put(KEY_ID, Question.ID);
        values.put(KEY_QUES, question.getQUESTION());
        values.put(KEY_OPTA, question.getOPTA());
        values.put(KEY_OPTB, question.getOPTB());
        values.put(KEY_OPTC, question.getOPTC());
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, question.getANSWER());

        values.put(KEY_ISIMAGE, question.getISIMAGE());
        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }
```

If I have left out any details, do let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Can u make a count query and check how many entries are there in that table?

Comment: there are 3 entries to the table. I use the DB Browser for SqLite program to check. So I am sure there are 3 questions inside. Or are you asking about how many items there are in the list.

Comment: In the table only. ok you are testing in emulator.?

Comment: Can u debug how many times the do while loop looping?